# Does Chumper/Datatable Laravel Package fetches the entire table every time it is called?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-5

I'm using Chumper/Datatable 
https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable

This is the code that I'm using to get json response for displaying the table.

```
$query = Article::select('title','id','created_at')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();

Datatable::collection($query)
    ->addColumn('id', function($model){
        return $model->id;
    })
    ->addColumn('title', function ($model) { return $model->accomodation ; })
    ->addColumn('created_at', function($model){
        return  Carbon::parse($model->created_at)->toFormattedDateString();
    })
    ->searchColumns('title', 'id')
    ->orderColumns('created_at','title','id')
    ->make();
```

So If I have 6000 rows.Does this package fetches all of them? If it does, then what's the alternative for an efficient query?

Answer (score 0):

It will do pretty much the same that you do when you paginate items - count, limit and only get what's needed, that's the whole point of datatable backend implementations.

As an example see this lines:

https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable/blob/master/src/Chumper/Datatable/Engines/QueryEngine.php#L243-L255